# Debug and Get around Disable Text Selection on Webpage

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am a new Web Developer, and I like to investigate how various websites implement strange features. I came across the following web-page: http://www.catholicmatch.com/forums/topics/posts.html?post_id=4664556#_jump_here

First, I am very curious how they manage to disable all selection. This is pretty impressive. How do they do it?

I first looked for `user-select: none` esp. in the `body` element and elsewhere, and I could not find it. I then looked for calls to `jquery.disableSelection()`. There seems to be one in the `$(document).ready()`, but it seems to apply to a small subset i.e. only in cases where a certain class is applied. I am really curious how these guys are implementing disabling selection, because even a **Ctrl+A** does not seem to work. This would be nice to have on a website I am working on.

Conversely, I am curious if there is a way to disable this behavior. For example I use [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/). Is there any command I can run in the **JavaScript Console**, or make a change in the **CSS** on the fly to disable this behavior? Of course, only once I know how this is implemented only could I attempt these changes.

I’d be grateful for any help. I am using the most up to date browsers in FireFox and Chrome.

Comment: This is counter-productive. I can understand why you want to know how it works, because it is cool. It's a good thing to be curious. But please don't implement this yourself.
Anyway, you will notice that if you right click on a part of the text there it will set your cursor, then if you hold shift+right-arrow it will let you select text. So it must have something to do with onClick, or a similar event.

Comment: I am curious why you say it is counter-productive? Once I know how a certain thing works, I do use prudence when to use it and how to use it. However, it all starts with knowing how it works.

Comment: I believe it's counter-productive because, well, firstly; why? Give me one legitimately good reason to do this. It's a waste of time and bandwidth. Why would you *ever* need/want to stop a user from selecting text. If they really want to they'll find a way. It isn't hard to get around. It's like disabling right-clicks on a site, there is no good reason, at all. Mainly because it won't actually do anything, most people can get around it.

Comment: Thank you **Jhawinsss**. I see what you say, and I agree with you - Sometimes non-programmer make decisions on what should be done, but if it were up to me, I agree with you.

Comment: **Jhawinsss** - I just saw you edited your first comment. In which browser did that **shift+right-arrow** work? I just realized that in older browsers, we can select, so this method is not fool proof.

Comment: its definitely not a good practice, except as some others pointed out to me for drag-able elements. If you have an element a user can drag, you may not want text selection to happen when they try. Also, I tried the shift+arrow thing on Safari 5.1.9 and Chrome 26, both on OSX 10.6.8.

Comment: I think this may be an **OSX** thing, because on **Windows Chrome 27**, I cannot get that shift+right arrow thing to work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are calling `.disableSelection()`. They just aren't calling it as you worded it. Below is a direct copy/paste from the source of the website.

Line 629 if you click "view source"

```
$(document).on('click', '.thumbActions button', thumbHandler).disableSelection();
```

[Check out this part of the documentation on `.disableSelection()`](http://api.jqueryui.com/disableSelection/):

> "Disabling text selection is bad. Don't use this."

The following code (also taken directly from the website's source) should make the way it actually works more obvious.

```
(function($){
    $.fn.disableSelection = function() {
        return this.attr('unselectable', 'on').css('user-select', 'none').on('selectstart', false);
    };
    $.fn.enableSelection = function() {
        return this.attr('unselectable', 'off').css('user-select', 'all').on('selectstart', true);
    };
})(jQuery);
```

It is setting the CSS rule `user-select` to `none` or `all`, depending on what should or shouldn't be selectable. At first I thought it was because of the HTML `unSelectable` attribute, but after actually trying it it doesn't appear to do anything. Maybe it's an IE only thing.
`user-select` definitely works though.

Comment: **Jhawinsss** - This explanation seems to be perfect. Why doesn't `user-select` not show up as one of the attributes when I look into **Firebug**? Is it because it is not standard?

Comment: Most likely you just aren't looking at the right element. I'm not sure. I can't look into it right now, but I definitely will late. I also couldn't see user-select when inspecting with Safari, but like I said, its probably just a different element. Try stepping up to parentNodes in console and checking for the attribute.